# Problems passing variable to private class in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, private, public

The script I'm working on processes form data: 3 text fields and two file uploads (one an image, the other a pdf doc). The script is successfully saving and naming the two files to the server, and saving the 3 text fields to sql db. However, **the url of the image and document are not saving to sql.**

The script is using two sql statememtns: The 1st one for the text fields, second for the file url's. The first sql is executed outside of my class CropAvatar. My rational was to pass the var $id (which is auto-increment in sql) obtained after the 1st sql execution, and then pass it to the second statement. I thought I achieved that through defining $id in the constructor and using it in the 2nd sql statement.

No success, the second sql statement appears not to be executing. Any suggestions on how to get the URL's of these two files submitted to sql? Or any suggestions on debugging here?

I'm not happy I'm posting 150+ lines of code here, I just have no clue where this is going wrong. I am still trying to wrap my head around the correct use of these private functions, and I have a feeling that my error is wrapped up somewhere in that. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

```
    <?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$titlee = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$address = $_POST['address'];
$addresse = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
$sale_price = $_POST['sale_price'];
    $sale_pricee= mysql_real_escape_string($sale_price);
require('../dbcon.php');
$sql="INSERT INTO listings (title, comment,transaction, date_added) VALUES ('$titlee', '$addresse, '$sale_pricee, now())";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
    class CropAvatar {
        private $src;
        private $data;
        private $file;
        private $dst;
        private $type;
        private $extension;
        private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
        private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
        private $msg;
function __construct($src, $data, $file, $id) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setId($id);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
}
        private $id;
        public function setId($id) {
                 $this->id = $id;
}
        private function setSrc($src) {
            if (!empty($src)) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($src);
                if ($type) {
                    $this -> src = $src;
                    $this -> type = $type;
                    $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $this -> setDst();
                }
            }
        }
        private function setData($data) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
            }
        }
        private function setFile($file) {
            $errorCode = $file['error'];
            if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);

                if ($type) {
                    $dir = $this -> srcDir;

                    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                        mkdir($dir, 0777);
                    }
$currdate=date('YmdHis');
                    $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;
                    if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

                        if (file_exists($src)) {
                            unlink($src);
                        }
                        $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
$listing_img="http://www.website.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
$allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
$tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
$extensionf = end($tempf);

if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
&& ($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] <2000000000)
&& in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
{
    $flyername=$_FILES["flyer"]["name"];

    if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }   
        else 
        {
            if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
            {
             echo $_FILES["flyer"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
                else 
                {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                 }
        }
      $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
      require('../dbcon.php');
$sql="update listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$ID";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_close($con);
}
                        if ($result) {
                            $this -> src = $src;
                            $this -> type = $type;
                            $this -> extension = $extension;
                            $this -> setDst();
                        } else {
                             $this -> msg = 'Failed to save file';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this -> msg = 'Please upload image with the following types: JPG, PNG, GIF';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = 'Please upload image file';
                }
            } else {
                $this -> msg = $this -> codeToMessage($errorCode);
            }
        }

        private function setDst() {
            $dir = $this -> dstDir;

            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777);
            }
            $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
        }
        private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
            if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                        break;
                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                        break;
                }
                if (!$src_img) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                    return;
                }
                $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
                $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);
                if ($result) {
                    switch ($this -> type) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;
                    }

                    if (!$result) {
                        $this -> msg = "Failed to save the cropped image file";
                    }
                } else {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to crop the image file";
                }
                imagedestroy($src_img);
                imagedestroy($dst_img);
            }
        }

        private function codeToMessage($code) {
            switch ($code) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    $message = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
                    break;               
                default:
                    $message = 'Unknown upload error';
            }
            return $message;
        }
        public function getResult() {
            return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
        }
        public function getMsg() {
            return $this -> msg;
        }
    }
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file'], $id);
    $response = array(
        'state'  => 200,
        'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
        'result' => $crop -> getResult()
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: looking into this thank you @tadman

Comment: Your whole code is not good. You are not supposed to use classes just because. A class wraps certain functionality and isolates it. Then the developer uses the class (and it's *public* methods) to perform a **specific** piece of work. You are mixing everything. You are also unaware what access control does to methods. What you've done in those 150 or so lines is wrapping procedural code into a class that's mostly not really usable. I'd advise you to use PDO for db access and to scrap this code and start over. The idea is to make code **easier** to read and maintain. Not harder.

Comment: @N.B. not having a good day

Answer (score 1):

I skimmed through your code, and you should probably print your quires to make sure, but in:

```
$sql="update listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$ID";
```

I can't see where the variable $ID is coming from, so the update will not work.
You can, and should use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) so that next time it would be easier for you to find your sql errors.

I hope that solves it.